# Column visibility based on 2 parameters in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have a parameter 'Section' which has values A,B,C  and another parameter 'Field' which has values X,Y,Z. now my requirement is i need to make column visibility based on both the parameters,if my parameter 'section' is A and parameter 'field' is X then the column should be shown else hidden.both are multi-valued parameters. I have written the following expression which is not allowing me to run

```
=IIF(InStr(JOIN(Parameters!Sections.Label,", "),"A"),InStr(JOIN(Parameters!Fields.Label,", "),"X", False,True),True)
```

Error i am getting while running the report is "Input string was not in a correct format.
Can anyone help me in correcting the format?

Comment: what should happen if you chose multiple select? column value should select base on row value ( like first row has 'A' and 'X' ) then value is blank , 2nd role has 'B' and 'Y' then value is there?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IIF(InStr(JOIN(Parameters!Sections.Label,", "),"A") And InStr(JOIN(Parameters!Fields.Label,", "),"X"), True,False)
```

Comment: Its not working when i select all in the 'Field' parameter which includes both X ,Y,Z

Comment: Is "All" a separate option in the available values, or do you mean when you check X, Y, & Z?  If the latter, then it should work unless you are not implementing correctly.